# How to access data in JSON response recieved from JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

How do I access the data stored in JSON that is returned in the complete function of a JQuery AJAX request. For example, I have the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'buildings.php',
    data: "building=" + building,
    complete: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
        alert(response.name);
    }
});
```

In the first alert it displays the following, which is the intended JSON data that I sent from PHP.

```
{"name":"HSB","description":"description","directionsURL":"directionsURL","imageArray":{"1":"URL 1","2":"URL 2"}}
```

In the second alert, it displays

```
undefined
```

**How do I access the data I received that is displayed in the first alert?**

Comment: I suspect you are getting response back as string. You can explicitly tell jquery to return json object. Add dataType: 'json' into your ajax request.  Default is intelligent guest based on your server response. (your server response might return as plain/text)

Comment: Try console.log(response). Show us the result of firebug console / or developer tools javascript console(if you are using google chrome)

Comment: @Connorelsea did you check to see if you're actually returning the right content-type header and valid JSON from your PHP script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `dataType: "json"` to the call the response will be made a json object:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'buildings.php',
    data: "building=" + building,
    dataType: "json",
    complete: function (response) {
        alert(response.name);
    }
});
```

Edit: so it appears that for whatever reason jQuery wasn't able to parse it automatically, but `JSON.parse(response.responseText)` did the trick.

Comment: The alert still produces undefined. This is [my code with your correct.](https://gist.github.com/Elsealabs/e7694afa9c5a54b67841)

Comment: Could you parse it before the change? like this `JSON.parse(response)`

Comment: This is the error I get when I remove the dataType and attempt to parse it using `var buildingObject = JSON.parse(response);`. http://i.imgur.com/a0T7nTU.png

Comment: My bad the code sample should've been `JSON.parse(response.responseText)`, does that make any difference?

Comment: The first comment has it right all except for the addition of `.responseText`. Can you edit your answer so it is more clear what the solution to the problem was? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Is your PHP script returning the correct MIME type in the headers? As shown here - [Returning JSON from a PHP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script)

If so, then add this to the options.

```
dataType: "json",
```

One of the easiest mistakes to make if your content header is right is that of returning a quoted string instead of the actual JSON. ie. the actual return contents being

```
"{ \"key\": \"value\" }"
```

instead of

```
{ "key": "value" }
```

Comment: @KevinB good point, didn't properly note the plain string data input

Answer (score 1):

You can you `jQuery.getJSON()` and check the contentType of the response

Answer (score 1):

It looks like **response.responseText** contains your JSON packet. Try something like this:

```
var json = JSON.parse(response.responseText); //assume response.responseText is a json string
console.log(json.name);
```

Comment: strings don't have name properties.

Comment: Very true... see edit.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP is simply returning a string that *looks* like a JSON object, but javascript isn't smart enough to know that you want it to be a JSON object.  Just parse the response before you act upon it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'buildings.php',
    data: "building=" + building,
    complete: function (response) {
        var json = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
        alert(json.responseText);
        alert(json.name);
    }
});
```

Comment: I figured it out. This would be correct, but instead of `JSON.parse(response)`, which gives an error, it should be `JSON.parse(response.responseText)`. Can you please add this to your answer for people looking at this in the future? When that is done I can mark this as the correct answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the catch.  I wasn't exactly sure how your original data was formatted.